# How to insert jQuery function in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

How can I insert this jQuery function I got in this forum.

This jQuery code is working, but based on my research, there is no way of creating a collision between images so I am trying to create a canvas.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
$(function () {
  $window = $('.window'),
    $bird = $('.bird'),
    fallTime = 1000,
    gapHeight = 120,
    gameState = 2,
    pipeId = 0;

  var int = setInterval(function () {
    if (gameState === 1) {
      spawnPipe();
      movePipes();
    }
  }, 1300);

  var birdPosInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if (gameState === 1) {
      birdPos();
    }
  }, 10);

  $window.mousedown(function () {
    birdFlap();
    if (gameState === 2) {
      gameState = 1;
      deleteInterval();
    }
  });

  $(window).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
      birdFlap();
      e.preventDefault();
      if (gameState === 2) {
        gameState = 1;
        deleteInterval();
      }
    }
  });

  function deleteInterval() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      var int = setInterval(function () {
        if (gameState === 1) {
          deletePipe();
        }
      }, 1300);
    }, 2050);
  }

  function birdFlap() {
    if (gameState === 1 || gameState === 2) {
      $bird.css('transform', 'rotate(-20deg)');
      $bird.stop().animate({
        bottom: '+=60px'
      }, 200, function () {
        birdPos();
        $bird.css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
        $bird.stop().animate({
          bottom: '-=60px'
        }, 300, 'linear', function () {
          birdPos();
          gravity();
        });
      });
    }
  }

  function gravity() {
    birdPercent = parseInt($bird.css('bottom')) / $window.height();
    totalFallTime = fallTime * birdPercent;
    $bird.stop().animate({
      bottom: '0'
    }, totalFallTime, 'linear');

    $bird.css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
  }

  function spawnPipe() {
    pipeId++;
    pipeTopHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($window.height() - 250)) +
      50;
    pipeBottomHeight = $window.height() - (pipeTopHeight + gapHeight);
    pipe = '<div class="pipe" pipe-id="' + pipeId +
      '"><div style="height: ' + pipeTopHeight +
      'px" class="topHalf"></div><div style="height:' + pipeBottomHeight +
      'px" class="bottomHalf"></div></div>';
    $window.append(pipe);
  }

  function deletePipe() {
    $('.window .pipe').first().remove();
  }

  function movePipes() {
    $('.pipe').each(function () {
      $(this).animate({
        right: '+=160px'
      }, 1300, 'linear');
    });
  }

  function birdPos() {
    if (parseInt($bird.css('bottom')) === 0) {
      gameEnd();
    }

    curPipe = $('.pipe:nth-of-type(4)');
    if (curPipe.length > 0) {
      pipeTop = $('.pipe:nth-of-type(4) .topHalf');
      pipeBottom = $('.pipe:nth-of-type(4) .bottomHalf');
      if (($bird.offset().left + $bird.width()) >= curPipe.offset().left &&
        $bird.offset().left <= (curPipe.offset().left + curPipe.width())) {
        if ($bird.offset().top < (curPipe.offset().top + pipeTop.height()) ||
          ($bird.offset().top + $bird.height()) > ((curPipe.offset().top +
            pipeTop.height()) + gapHeight)) {
          gameEnd();
        }
      } else if ($bird.offset().left >= (curPipe.offset().left +
          curPipe.width())) {
        $('.score').text(curPipe.attr('pipe-id'));
      }
    }
  }

  function gameEnd() {
    clearInterval(birdPosInterval);
    $('.pipe').stop();
    gravity();
    gameState = 0;
  }
})

and heres my js(canvas)

var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
  myGameArea.start();
  myGamePiece = new component(60, 70,
    "https://s28.postimg.org/k90gybbtl/bird_Sprite.png", 10, 120, "image");
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function () {
    this.canvas.width = 1000;
    this.canvas.height = 500;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    //insert bec I added image
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function () {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  },
  stop: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  if (type == "image") {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = color;
  }
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function () {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (type == "image") {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image,
        this.x,
        this.y,
        this.width, this.height);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  }
  this.newPos = function () {
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();

}
```

Comment: What??? Canvas is an element, you don't insert code, you use the canvas to render. Collision is just testing if two objects overlap, search AABB collision detection (Axis Aligned Bounding Boxes) to do collisions. If the code you have is an example then you should find a better one as it is the best example of bad practice I have seen for some time. Lookup `requestAnimationFrame` for animating, don't use setInterval (surprised it's not flickering like crazy)  and don't use jQuery inside animation code

Comment: okay thank you for the information. Let's say that I want to create a collision between images/divs, is that even possible? The scenario I wanted is when the bird hit the letter (for example) , the letter will fall and will go in another place. the bird will not die because hitting the letters will be counted as the score. Any suggest or advice on how I will pursue this, please this is for our project. Thank you